# I18n localization time format for spanish translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, time-format

I am using I18n for localizing a rails application, and i came across a situation which involves time format using I18n.

the date and time format displaying is as follows: `"Tuesday, July 11, 2017"` for time : `2017-07-11 12:30:00 +0530`

for localizing i am using `en.yml` and `es.yml` with both time formats as shown below:

```
 en:
  time:
   formats:
     long: '%A, %B %d, %Y'
     short: '%b %d, %Y'
```

and in model i am using `I18n.l(raw_date.to_time, format: :long)`, this working fine for english with result `"Tuesday, July 11, 2017"`, but for spanish its returning like this: `"a, t 11, 2017"`

what is the datetime format for spanish to get the same result as english.   any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [rails-i18n spanish file](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml), I've pulled a couple of their translations over and everything seems to be working as expected (I saw the same issue until I added these translations).

**config/locales/es.yml**

```
es:
  date:
    day_names:
      - domingo
      - lunes
      - martes
      - miércoles
      - jueves
      - viernes
      - sábado
    month_names:
      -
      - enero
      - febrero
      - marzo
      - abril
      - mayo
      - junio
      - julio
      - agosto
      - septiembre
      - octubre
      - noviembre
      - diciembre
  time:
    formats:
      long: '%A, %B %d, %Y'
      short: '%b %d, %Y'
```

and then in the console:

```
I18n.locale = :es
I18n.l(Date.today.to_time, format: :long) # => "viernes, julio 21, 2017"
```

I recommend taking a look at the rest of their file (or even pulling in the entire thing) if you're doing a lot of translations with rails built in stuff.

Notes:

- I don't speak Spanish, so I just assume that their file is alright
- There are a fair number of other date translations you may need if you are using a different format

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was missing date, days_name and months_name in es.yml. it worked once i added.