# Internationalization of local_time (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Simple question, but quite important please. 
I have a field in my view : `@event.start_time` which I applied local_time to, since the table uses UTC as a default, but users can be from anywhere.

I would like to translate the time from english to the current user's locale. 
 as of now my field looks like `<%= local_time(@event.start) %>`.

I tried `<%= I18n.l(local_time(@event.start), format: :long) %>` and obviously it does not work, as it expects a date object, not a string.

Anybody knows how to handle please?

Thanks

Comment: Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235207/i18n-localization-time-format-for-spanish-translation

Comment: @LHH Thanks a lot, my issue is not to translate time, it is to translate time knowing that I am using local_time gem please.

Comment: This is simply broken right now, see: https://github.com/basecamp/local_time/issues/108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use the Internationalization here, local_time gem supports it but for that you will have to supply the set of translations, for example if you check the [`i18n.coffee`](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/src/local-time/config/i18n.coffee) file of the gem you will find the default English translation set already added and similarly you can [add for others](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time#configuration).

**Example:**

```
LocalTime.config.i18n["es"] = {
  date: {
    dayNames: [ … ],
    monthNames: [ … ],
    …
  },
  time: {
    …
  },
  datetime: {
    …
  }
}

LocalTime.config.locale = "es"
```

**Source:** https://github.com/basecamp/local_time#configuration

The other option would be that if you have their timezone saved in your database you can convert the UTC time to particular timezone and then pass to the `I18n.l` which will convert the time in your required format. For this either you can set the `Time.zone` directly to the user's timezone or use `in_time_zone` method to convert UTC time to user's time. To set the `Time.zone` directly you can add a `before_action` in `ApplicationController` like this:

```
before_action :set_time_zone

def set_time_zone
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone if current_user
end
```

Now whenever you will fetch the time for this particular session it will return it in the user's timezone so you will not have to convert it each time.